# Disable xscroll ipad

Tags: css, ipad, overflow

I'm currently hidding the x scroll with this (below), however it is still actually visible on ipad and functional in desktop browser (Chrome). Any ideas to completely loss it?

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a **jquery.ui.touch.js** file on the site usually prevents vertical scroll, just block it !